# Generating datatables child (more detail) row: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function "

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm trying to generate child rows as per the instructions here:

http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

The Datatable is doing exactly what it's supposed to, all the data is there, it's filtering and sorting properly.  But when I trigger the event listener, I get an error at this line:

```
 var row = table.row(tr);

 Specific error:  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.
```

Any ideas?  I've trawled the documentation and cannot see where the problem is.

My code is as follows:

Javascript:

```
function format(d) {
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' + '<tr>' + '<td>Summary: ' + d.summary + '</td>' + '</tr>' + '</table>';
};
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable( {
    "ajax": ajax,
    "bPaginate":true,
    "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
    "iDisplayLength": 25

});
//  event listener for child row
$('#datatable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // close open rows
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
        // Open selected row
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you try to reproduce this using a fiddle? Very weird that `closest()` is not recognized as a function

Comment: So very sorry; it is the subsequent line that triggers the error:  `var row = table.row(tr);`